# jQuery data element always undefined, why

Tags: jquery, html

I have looked at numerous posts, but can't see what I am doing that is different to what is suggested everywhere else.

I have the following :

```
<select class="SS2" name="nSS">
    <option class="SSO" data-section="1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select an Option</option>
    <option class="SSO" data-section="1" value="1">option 1</option>
    <option class="SSO" data-section="1" value="2">option 2</option>
</select>
</br>
```

I then have the following jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('change', '.SS2', function() {
        var id1 = $(this).data('section');
        var id2 = $(this).val();
        alert(id1);
        alert(id2);
    })
});
</script>
```

When it runs `alert(id1)` it comes up as undefined, but `alert(id2)` works as expected. 
Can anyone explain why I can't pick up the `data('section')`.

I have also tried using `$(this).attr('data-section')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(this)` inside the event handler refers to the `<select>` element which don't have `data-section` attribute.

To get the value of the selected `<option>`, you can use `option:selected` selector.

```
var id1 = $(this).children('option:selected').data('section');
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('change', '.SS2', function() {
    var id1 = $(this).children('option:selected').data('section');
    var id2 = $(this).val();
    alert(id1);
    // alert(id2);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="SS2" name="nSS">
  <option class="SSO" data-section="1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select an Option</option>
  <option class="SSO" data-section="1" value="1">option 1</option>
  <option class="SSO" data-section="1" value="2">option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: of course. why didn't I see that . . . Cheers for that.

Comment: @IGGt Glad that helped :)